# Thread Within Struct that Mutates self

Tags: rust, concurrency, distributed-computing

I am trying to implement the raft consensus algorithm using Rust.
First I am trying to implement some sort of local message exchange between 2 servers.

This is my server struct:

```
pub struct Server {
    my_id: u8,
    senders: Vec<(u8, Sender<String>)>,
    receivers: Vec<Mutex<Receiver<String>>>,
    message_queue: Vec<String>,
    request_message_queue: Vec<String>,
    running: bool,
}
```

I am failing in writing a thread that receives the messages sent by the senders.

```
pub fn send_message(&self, to: u8, message: String) {
    self.senders.iter().for_each(|(id, sender)| {
        if to == *id {
            sender.send(message.clone()).unwrap();
        }
    });
}

pub fn init(&'static mut self) {
    self.running = true;

    thread::scope(move |scope| {
        scope.spawn(move |scope| {
            self.receivers.iter().for_each(|rec| {
                let r = rec.lock().unwrap();
                if !r.is_empty() {
                    r.recv().unwrap();
                }
                drop(r)
            });
        });
    })
    .expect("HEY");
}
```

With the code above I keep getting this error after calling the init method in the main.

```
 server1.lock().unwrap().init();
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----------------
   |     |
   |     borrowed value does not live long enough
   |     argument requires that `server1` is borrowed for `'static`
...
24 | }
   | - `server1` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I also believe that my main function is far for good. Should I be using this many mutexes?

```
fn main() {
    let mut server1 = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Server::new(0)));
    let mut server2 = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Server::new(1)));
    let mut server3 = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Server::new(2)));

    server1.lock().unwrap().init();

    server1.lock().unwrap().connect(server2.clone());
    server1.lock().unwrap().connect(server3.clone());

    server1
        .lock()
        .unwrap()
        .send_message(1, "HELLO WORLD".to_string());
    server1
        .lock()
        .unwrap()
        .send_message(1, "HELLO WORLD".to_string());

    server2.lock().unwrap().receive();
}
```

Could some one please explain how can this be done. The idea is that I want to be able to send and receive the messages at the same time.

Comment: You can't ever take a `&'static` reference to non static data, but just removing the `'static` from `init` should fix that immediate problem.

Comment: nit: Your scoped thread in `init` does nothing, your main thread is just waiting for the scoped thread to finish and then immediately joins it.

Comment: Could you please add the `use` statements for the types you use, for example `Sender` being as general as a name as it is appears in several crates and in `std`, in general provide a [mre] not just severeal loosely related bits of your code.

Comment: @cafce25 The sender comes from the crossbeam crate. Sorry for not adding that.

Comment: Your code is highly incomplete. `Server` does not have a `receive` or `connect` function. `message_queue` and `request_message_queue` members are completely unused. The `init` function only receives once, not repeatedly. It's completely unclear what the `1` in your `main`'s `send_message` stands for; it is an ID that never got created anywhere, it's a purely magic number. Please provide more information or clean up your code so it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing here is what @cafce25 already mentioned - your `init` function does nothing in regard of threading. `scope` can only use the `self` reference because it blocks until the spawned thread returns - and because of that you could use the initial thread in the first place. No multi-threading takes place here.

In fact, the problem is bigger than that - you cannot and will never be able to use a reference to some outside object inside of a thread.

The idea of having multiple threads access the same data is a paradigm that comes from C, but isn't compatible with Rust. In C, the programmer is responsible for making sure that multithreading doesn't cause undefined behaviour - in Rust, the compiler is responsible for that. That gives great confidence, but also comes with more limitations than the C language.

For example, you cannot and will never be able to have a `&mut self` pointer that can be accessed from a thread while there's also a `&self` reference somewhere else that can be used to call `send_message`. The only solution here is a rethinking of your struct layout.

What I would probably do is to split the `Server` struct into three parts:

- things that have to be reachable from the outside
- things that are owned by the thread
- things that have to be accessed by both (like `running`). This part probably needs to be behind an `Arc` and some interior mutability somewhere.

I can't help you further, though, because many parts of your code don't make much sense to me.